# In which episode of "Rick & Morty" does Jerry go into labour?

Tags: rick-and-morty

Jerry is shown going into labour in the opening credits but I have not seen it in any episode. Am I missing any?

[image: Pregnant Jerry]

Comment: No, it's not in any episode yet.

Comment: oh thanks , it would be one hilarious sketch if they added it in season 3

Comment: Check your interdimensional TV, eventually you'll find it.

Comment: It's in the episode where we learn Evil Morty's true identity, don't you remember?

Answer (score 15):

There are several parts in the opening that aren't present in the episodes. IIRC there was an interview with an animator and he said they were just done for the opening. And Jerry giving birth isn't the only one that isn't in an episode. There's also Morty's face falling off revealing that he's a robot(?).

Comment: And when Rick, Morty, and Summer are being chased by Cthulhu.

Comment: In the newest episode (S03E02) the intro credits seem to show several scenes redone in alternate dimensions (butt-faces-with-face-butts universe for example).

Comment: Morty's face falling off could be a quick reference to the first few episodes, where Jerry very much dislikes how Rick distracts Morty from school. While not shown explicitly in any episode, robot Morty very quickly creates that understanding that R&M go behind Jerry's back ([**literally** in that scene](https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/rickandmorty/images/2/2c/Opening_robot_morty.png/revision/latest?cb=20160915164232)), and that notion _is_ elaborated on in the show (mainly the pilot).